# Imagemagick: How does RGB work with this software?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to change all colors #FF00FF in an image to #0000FF while keeping shades, ideally. So I figured I should at least get it to change colors to begin with to see if the software is even capable of doing things like that.

However its only changing a bit of the color to white and only with a high Fuzz. So it's obvious that RGB in Imagemagick doesn't work like it does anywhere else and I can't find anything to explain how it works.

It seems to replace some off-white with pure white.

Using PHP I do:

```
exec("convert ".$dir."".$file." -channel RGB -fuzz 30% -opaque rgb\(255,0,255\) -fill rgb\(0,0,255\) ".$dir."".$file);
```

Comment: This seems very unclear in its current form. You don't want to change *only* those colours, but similar ones, too, correct? Can you show an example of what you want, and how IM is not doing what you want?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me to post images when posting about modifying images, however the answer is complete, thanks for the suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% certain what you mean as you haven't provided a sample of what other software does, but I'll have a try and see if we can get there.

So, if we make a starting image, including your presumed shades of magenta on the left and some test colours on the right:

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient:black-magenta -size 50x256 \
   xc:black xc:white xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append start.png
```

[image]

And, you want to change magenta shades into blue. I would call that a hue modulation, so I would want to find out the hue angle between blue and magenta, so I would create a 2x1 image with one magenta and one blue pixel and get their HSI values:

```
convert xc:magenta xc:blue -append -colorspace hsi txt:
```

**Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,2,65535,hsi
0,0: (54612.5,65535,43690)  #D555FFFFAAAA  hsi(300,100%,66.6667%)
0,1: (43690,65535,21845)  #AAAAFFFF5555  hsi(240,100%,33.3333%)
```

And I can see their hues are 60 degrees apart (300-240). So I would use the `-modulate` operator, which takes a *Brightness*, *Saturation* and *Hue*, leave the first two unchanged at 100%, and modify the *Hue* by 60 degrees:

```
convert start.png -modulate 100,100,60 result.png
```

[image]

---

Or maybe that is not what you mean? Maybe you only mean to affect  specific colour. If so, it gets harder... but not that hard :-)

First, extract the Hue, Saturation and Brightness layers to separate files:

```
convert start.png -colorspace HSL -separate -colorspace gray HSL-%d.png
```

That will give us the Hue as a single channel greyscale image in `HSL-0.png`, the Saturation in `HSL-1.png` and the Lightness in `HSL-2.png`.

Now we want to make a new LUT (Lookup Table) for the Hue channel, so we make a 360 pixel long LUT that maps 1:1, i.e. everything maps to normal.

```
convert -size 1x360 gradient: -rotate 90 greyscale.png
```

[image]

Then we want to dink with the lookups around magenta (300) and make them blue (240). So we want to subtract 60 degrees (which is 0.16 if you scale 0-360 degrees onto the range 0-1) from all pixels in the range 280-320 so there is some tolerance:

```
convert -size 1x360 gradient: -rotate 90 -colorspace gray -fx "i<280||i>320?u:u-0.16" hueCLUT.png
```

[image]

Now apply that LUT to the Hue of the original image and rebuild it...

```
convert HSL-0.png -colorspace gray hueCLUT.png -clut  HSL-1.png HSL-2.png -set colorspace HSL -combine -colorspace RGB result.png
```

[image]

So, as a simpler script, that might become:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make a hue CLUT, transforming magenta hues to blue
convert -size 1x360 gradient: -rotate 90 -colorspace gray -fx "i<295||i>305?u:u-0.16" -resize 256x1! hueclut.png

# Apply to the hue channel
convert start.png -colorspace HSL -write MPR:HSL \
        -channel R -separate hueclut.png -clut   \
        \( MPR:HSL -channel G -separate \)       \
        \( MPR:HSL -channel B -separate \)       \
        -set colorspace HSL -combine -colorspace RGB result.png
```

Comment: The copy & paste of the "simpler script" didn't work, however, I wrote one following the above commands you posted and it just works. Grey becomes a bit darker too, but that's not unexpected when playing with hue.

Comment: I'm glad we got there in the end and it works for you. Maybe try changing the final RGB to sRGB to see if that helps. Good luck with your project!